# Convert ms into a string date with Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I have a timestamp as ms and format this with a SimpleDateFormater like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yyyy h:mm a");

return sdfDate.format(new Date(timeStamp));
```

Now I'd like to change this to use the new Java 8 abilities. Seems like I really can't find a way to get this working with the new Java 8 Classes. Anyone got a hint?

Comment: `Date` is deprecated in `java 8`. what about `LocalDate`

Comment: @Satya, `Date` is not declared as deprecated in Java-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you have is a millisecond value (assuming from the Unix Epoch) you can get an `LocalDateTime` using something like:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMillis), ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Which can print something like:

```
2015-09-29T16:57:40.077
```

You can then format it using something like this:

```
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a")));
```

Which can print something like (based on the original time from the previous example):

```
09/29/2015 4:57 PM
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Beside of Date is deprecated in Java 8, why is this "better" than my 2 lines of Code?

Comment: Well, it's still two lines of code (in fact I could make it one), but the new Time API is simple easier and more power to use.  Rather then having `Date` AND `Calendar` and all the fun stuff surrounding those.  I also thing the time zoning is better handled (in respect of how people understand it) (oh and `java.util.Date` isn't depreciated, it is however redundant given the power of the new Time/Date API)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can try this in Java 8 to get Date from timestamp:

```
timeStamp.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
```

For formatting you can use LocalDateTime as:

```
String str = "1997-03-18 11:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```