# How to convert milliseconds into Timestamp using Talend

Tags: timestamp, etl, talend, milliseconds

I have csv file where time_column is in milliseconds, Which I want in Timestamp(date & time). I have more than 100 rows which I need to convert.

```
Input :

1587740000000
1590600000000 
1588880000000
1589040000000
1589040000000

Output:
24-04-2020 20:23:20
27-05-2020 22:50:00
08-05-2020 01:03:20
09-05-2020 21:30:00
09-05-2020 21:30:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ms into a string date with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837406/convert-ms-into-a-string-date-with-java-8). Search for many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this might help

[Converting a Unix timestamp to a readable date- Talend](https://help.talend.com/reader/RcB_Bc_X7moXbmemvIXXEg/TU%7EjHn8sDy5XrScSwoiiuw)

Using Java:-

```java
//As string
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(epoch*1000));
//Epoch in seconds, remove '*1000' for milliseconds.

//As Date
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(epoch*1000);
//Epoch in seconds, remove '*1000' for milliseconds.
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Sure @OleV.V. But `SimpleDateFormat` is still widely used and taught everywhere.

Comment: If so, that’s the problem. Don’t be part of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way using tJava ot tJavaflex.
Below is the code,

```
long Milliseconds = 1587740000000L;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(Milliseconds)));
```

[image]

You can also create routine out of it and use it as a function in tMap

Answer (score 0):

If you’re fine with a solution in Java, do go for java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The `SimpleDateFormat` class suggested in a couple of other answers is a notorious troublemaker of a class, do yourself the favour of staying a good distance away from it.

```
    DateTimeFormatter millisecondFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .toFormatter();
    
    String[] timeStringsFromCsv = {
            "1587740000000",
            "1590600000000",
            "1588880000000",
            "1589040000000",
            "1589040000000"
    };
    
    for (String timeString : timeStringsFromCsv) {
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = millisecondFormatter
                .parse(timeString, Instant::from)
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2020-04-24T20:23:20+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
> 2020-05-27T22:50+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
> 2020-05-08T01:03:20+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
> 2020-05-09T21:30+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
> 2020-05-09T21:30+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
> ```

As you can see, I had my JVM’s default time zone set to Asia/Colombo when I ran the code. If your time zone is different, your results will be too.

If you require the output formatted into new strings, use a second `DateTimeFormatter` for that.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.