# SimpleDateFormat not working on 1629777600000

Tags: java, spring, simpledateformat

Date format coming from the database: 1629777600000

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

simpleDateFormat.format(1629777600000);

When using this simple date format I am not able to convert 1629777600000 to a viewable date

Comment: what is `1629777600000` time in millis since epoch time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "unixtime" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java)

Comment: @jmj Yes, that is what I am trying to determine as well. Its coming from Oracle SQL database

Comment: Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_629_777_600_000L).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))`. Yields `08/24/2021`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ms into a string date with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837406/convert-ms-into-a-string-date-with-java-8). Sorry that I was too slow to close your question as a duplicate before others closed it otherwise. It may also be that it should better have been closed as caused by a typo, though?

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormatter.format(1629777600000L));
```

Print: `08/24/2021`

---

But **your** code does not compile:

- you initialize `simpleDateFormatter` but use `simpleDateFormat` (without `ter`)
- `1629777600000` is a Long, therefore it needs an `L` at its end

I think the `L` problem is just from modifiying the code for the stackoverflow question. But the variable name is maybe a real problem in your code.